# How to create hibernate composite key and get values from table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to use hibernate annotations for getting data from a MySQL database table which doesn't have a primary key defined.

However the fact is 2 columns of that table together are unique in the table. How can I achieve the same using hibernate annotation?

This is my code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "coc_order_view")
public class CoCOrderDetailsTest {

@EmbeddedId
private MyJoinClassKey key;

@Column(name = "coupon_code")
private String couponCode;

some other columns and their getters and setters .....

@Embeddable
public class MyJoinClassKey implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5L;

@Column(name = "product_id")
private int productId;

@Column(name = "order_id")
private int orderId;

gettes and setters....
```

And here is my criteria query

```
Criteria criteria = getHibernatetemplate().getSession().createCriteria(CoCOrderDetailsTest.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", "New"));
ArrayList<CoCOrderDetailsTest> orderDet = (ArrayList<CoCOrderDetailsTest>) getHibernatetemplate().get(criteria);
```

I am unable to get all the values from db. Kindly suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through your question again not sure this will help.  You can't have a table without primary key(s).  Read the first couple of paragraphs in [this article](http://www.javabeat.net/jpa-primary-key-id-idclass/)

That said, if you can alter the table and add primary keys on those fields you need to add @IdClass annotation to your class signature for CoCOrderDetailsTest and then get rid of the @embeddable and @embeddedId notation in your classes.

Another alternative, if you can add a field to the table, would be to use an [@GeneratedValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) on that added primary key field and of course annotate it with @Id.

If you can't alter the table then you can't use JPA and you'll have to use JDBC.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html

A working example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player_game_log")
@IdClass(PlayerGameLogId.class)
public class PlayerGameLog {

@Id
@Column(name = "PLAYER_ID")
private Integer playerId;

@Id
@Column(name = "GAME_ID")
private String gameId;
....
```

and the id class (note there are no annotations on the id class)....

```
public class PlayerGameLogId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer playerId;
private String gameId;
```

Try:

```
String hql = "FROM CoCOrderDetailsTest WHERE status = :status";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("status","New");
List results = query.list();
```

I usually use EntityManager rather than session so I'm not familiar with this syntax - and I have typically added a type to the list to be returned - like:

```
List<CoCOrderDetailsTest> results = query.list();
```

Comment: It is not working buddy. Should I add equal and hashcode??

Comment: I'll add a snippet to the above.  See if you can get anything back.